# Generating xml attribute value of a file by counting a certain string using LINQ 2 XML?

Tags: c#, xml

I have some XML files in which may contain nodes `<disp-formula id="deqn*">` and each of these nodes have a string called `\tag` in it. Now the number of keyword `\tag` could be one or more in each node `<disp-formula id="deqn*">`.

I want to generate the attribute value `id` starting from 1, then increment to +1 for every `<disp-formula id="deqn*">` found using the `\tag` count.

Sample data:

```
<disp-formula id="deqn*">...\tag...</disp-formula>
<disp-formula id="deqn*">...\tag...\tag...\tag ...</disp-formula>
<disp-formula id="deqn*">...\tag ...</disp-formula>
<disp-formula id="deqn*">...\tag...\tag ...</disp-formula>
```

Expected modification:

```
<disp-formula id="deqn1">...\tag...</disp-formula>
<disp-formula id="deqn2-4">...\tag...\tag...\tag ...</disp-formula>
<disp-formula id="deqn5">...\tag ...</disp-formula>
<disp-formula id="deqn6-7">...\tag...\tag ...</disp-formula>
```

For generating numbers for a certain string I basically use the below process:

```
string inputText = File.ReadAllText(@"C:\temp\sample.xml");
string findText = @"*";  

int matchCount = inputText.Split(findText.ToCharArray()).Length - 1;  

if (matchCount > 0)  
{  
    for (int counter = 1; counter <= matchCount; counter++)  
    {  
        var regex = new Regex(Regex.Escape(findText));  
        inputText = regex.Replace(inputText, counter.ToString(), 1);  
    }  
}
```

But I can't figure out how to add the `\tag` counter in this method or how can I use LINQ2XML to get this job done?
Can anyone help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try like this;

```
XDocument doc = XDocument.Load("disp.xml");
var deqns = doc.Descendants("disp-formula");
int countIndex = 1;
foreach (var deqn in deqns)
{
    var matchCount = deqn.Value.Select((c, i) => deqn.Value.Substring(i)).Count(sub => sub.StartsWith("\\tag"));
    if (matchCount > 0)
    {
        int lastMatchCount = countIndex + matchCount - 1;
        var attribute = string.Format("deqn-{0}", countIndex);
        if (lastMatchCount > countIndex)
        {
            attribute = attribute + "-" + lastMatchCount;
        }
        deqn.Attribute("id").Value = attribute;
        countIndex = lastMatchCount + 1;
    }
}
doc.Save("disptarget.xml");
```

Comment: Thanks, could you explain(break down) the line `var matchCount = deqn.Value.Select((c, i) => deqn.Value.Substring(i)).Count(sub => sub.StartsWith("\\tag"));` ?

Comment: It returns the matched string count inside a string.. The matched '\tag' count calculated for  every ' disp-formula' element in the loop.

Comment: I know that, but I wanted to know how it works...I've never used 2D variables `(c, i)` in LINQ before...

Comment: "c" represents the per char of string and "i" is index of the char. Substring has been applied for per i index and the matched count is found by "startswith" for every substring. I suggest you to write this line and debug it, It provide better understanding. "var substrings = deqn.Value.Select((c, i) => deqn.Value.Substring(i)).ToList();"

Answer (score 0):

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var xmlStr =
        @"<root>
            <disp-formula id='deqn*'>...\tag...</disp-formula>
            <disp-formula id='deqn*'>...\tag...\tag...\tag ...</disp-formula>
            <disp-formula id='deqn*'>...\tag ...</disp-formula>
            <disp-formula id='deqn*'>...\tag...\tag ...</disp-formula>
        </root>";

    var xml = XElement.Parse(xmlStr);

    int x = 0;
    xml.Elements().ToList().ForEach(node =>
    {
        var count = Regex.Matches(node.Value, @"\\tag").Count;
        if (count > 0)
        {
            string start = (x + 1).ToString();
            string end = (x += count).ToString();
            string period = end == start ? start : $"{start}-{end}";
            node.Attribute("id").Value = "deqn" + period;
        }
    });

    Console.WriteLine(xml);
}
```